# Correct pronunciation of הנתונים בצרה ובשביה

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk

In the Tefillah of "Acheinu", we discuss our brothers who are "נתונים בצרה ובשביה". I have heard these words vowelized with a Pasach under the Beis of both terms (Batzarah Uvashivya, which would mean "in **the** trouble and/or in **the** captivity").  However, it would seem to make more sense to vowelize it with a Sheva, which would than mean "in trouble and/or in captivity".  I definitely remember seeing some Siddurim with a Sheva under each Beis.

I am looking to find out

1. if one version is more authentic than the other
2. any sources that discuss this
3. any proofs or other thoughts that Mi Yodea readers have on this

(Note that in Tanach, we do find the word Batzara in a few places (e.g. Tehillim 81:8), although many of the Mefarshim (e.g. see Rashi and Ibn Ezra there) discuss specific Tzaros that the Passuk may be referring to.)

Thanks!

Comment: Artscroll's Siddur Yitzchak Ya'ir and Nachalat Shimon have sh'va under both as does The Koren "Ani Tefilla". The 1986 Greenfield Siddur Hashalem has a patach under each as does the Siddur Shilo.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you happen to know the sources for any of those siddurim (i.e. where they would have gotten the nikkud from)?

Comment: I was looking in them to see if any gives a source for text (biblical or otherwise) but none does. The Beurei Hatefilla website has no vowels... http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2008-04-25Tefila_Newsletter.pdf

Comment: The Siddur, Avodas Yisroel, the definitive Ashkenazic Siddur of the 1800’s “Avodas Yisroel” by Rabbi Zeligman Baer has the version with the sheva under each beis.  

The [Siddur Tefilo Sefas Yisroel, a nusaḥ Ashkenaz siddur dedicated to the memory of the Bad Homburg Jewish community](http://opensiddur.org/compilations/siddurim/siddur-bnei-ashkenaz-a-german-rite-siddur-prepared-by-r-rallis-wiesenthal/)  has  בְּצָרָה וּבַשִּׁבְיָה one sheva and one patach.  - - A grammarian should offer his views.

Comment: The semantically similar verse מי נתן לִמשיסה יעקב וישראל לְבוזזים might be a reason to go with the shva

Comment: @Avrahom Yitzhok Thanks!  What makes Avodas Yisroel definitive?  Also, as a non-grammarian, perhaps the version with one and one was referring to a particular event for Shivya, but only general Tzara, meaning it was written with a particular Shivya in mind.

Comment: I was wondering why I didn't recognize the tefillah you speak of... I looked in the Chabad siddur and saw that it deletes this "Acheinu" line out of the nusach. So since I daven Nusach Chabad I never knew it existed.

Comment: _The Authorised Daily Prayer Book of the United Hebrew Congregations of the British Empire_ (what a mouthful) has a _sheva_ under the _beit_.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות There aren't any Yehi Ratzons either. It just goes straight from "Vezos haTorah" to Ashrei. Weird, huh? See here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32581&st=&pgnum=70

Comment: _Siddur Tefilat Kol Peh_ has a patach.

Comment: @ezra Thanks.  I wonder why Chabad doesn't have it, if other communities also don't say it, and why?

Comment: Perhaps the patach migrated from *bayam* and *bayabasha*.

Comment: @Loewian interesting theory. Do you have any very early sources that have Shevas on those words?  In the comments so far, the earliest indication of the Nikkud is from sometime in the 1800s, and the Tefillah itself is from at least the time of the Gaonim (it's found in Seder Rav Amram), so I'm not convinced that it started with Shevas.

Comment: I should have said duplicated rather than migrated - as in for symmetry.

Comment: No worries, I didn't think they had left bayam and bayabasha...  Are you suggesting that it was done intentionally by someone to match them up, or that people just started reading it like that?

Comment: Emden writes it with shva in this 1745 edition of his siddur (and he was quite well-versed in grammar):
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19725&st=&pgnum=322

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Unfortunately in many cases, with the best intentions involved, Heidenheim and Baer were mistaken (at least if you accept Ben Asher more authoritative on nikud). A nice example that you all know is the word חסדי in the Amidah. Both Heidenheim and Baer writes the dalet with dagesh (see also in appendix also Psalm 107:43):
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19723&st=&pgnum=53
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42897&st=&pgnum=112

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok [Cont.] However both Keter Aleppo and the Leningrad Codex are clearly without dagesh (and that is how Artscroll brings it):
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Aleppo-HighRes3-Ketuvim2-Psalms.pdf&page=42
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Leningrad-codex-15-psalms.pdf&page=47
Obviously they didn't have the sources we have, they had to figure out the rules on their own, but they are not infallible. The thing to admire in their work is that they are consistent even in mistakes, which was quite a big thing in the era of manual typesetting.

Comment: The original versions of this prayer can be found in Siddur Rav Amram Ga'on after Mon. / Thurs. *Gelilah* or Machzor Vitri after Shabbat Mincha Torah reading. The hebrewbooks.com scanned version does not have vowels for these prayers, so I can't verify what these versions are. Suffice to say that if you can locate the vowelization in either of these sources, they are far older than Art Scroll, Birnbaum or anything else most shuls are using.

Comment: Gramattically, it doesn't sound like having the definite form (with the patach) is incorrect. It could be a "collective" noun signifying a "status" or "condition". It's similar to people saying, "I have THE flu."

Comment: @DanF in fact, I used to ask people which Tzara and which Shivya it referred to... ;)

Comment: @DanF These works (at least the manuscripts we have) were not menukad at the time when they were written. Only Vitry has some parts in some manuscripts with vowels.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Good info. I assume it, of course, was a question of hand-written items, at the time, and no one thought of vowelizing, then, anyway. Lack of that info is prob. what's causing the doubt in pronunciation. I still think that either pronunciation makes sense, and this is just a matter of preference or different *nuscha'ot*, for whatever reason.

Comment: Re Chabad's omission - I think beureihatefilah.com's article mentions that this was originally designated to be said only on Shabbat mevarchim hachodesh. Of course, if so, I have a feeling that Chaba"d isn't saying it then, either, so I don't know why they eliminate it. Maybe it's considered a *hefsek* for some reason?

Comment: [This Siddur](https://books.google.com/books?id=54piAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT96&lpg=PT96&dq=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%94+%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%94&source=bl&ots=763Vxo5aKm&sig=3ALUxdR4DjLJn3WHUSf_cT1UKuA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKl662n8_aAhUHn1MKHclwCO0Q6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%94&f=false), written by "The grammarian [R' Shlomo Zalman Hanau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Hanau)", contains a *Sheva* by both. [Cont.]

Comment: [Cont.] Considering that R' Yaakov Emden, who was a fierce critic of R' Shlomo Zalman Hanau (according to Wikipedia), [also has a *Sheva*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87805/correct-pronunciation-of-%d7%94%d7%a0%d7%aa%d7%95%d7%a0%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%91%d7%a6%d7%a8%d7%94-%d7%95%d7%91%d7%a9%d7%91%d7%99%d7%94#comment282010_87805), I would think it's safe to assume that this is the more grammatically correct version. (Should this be an answer?)